# How can I get and format the node created date in field.html.twig?

Tags: 8, theming

The date is being rendered from field.html.twig template from {{ item.content }} from "items" array. After Using a twig filter date {{ items.content|date("long") }} it only outputs current date not the date node was created. How could I achieve node submitted date instead of the current date. [image]

Answer (score 6):

Having a field template you always can get the parent entity via `element['#object']`. And from there you can get everything else, also the creation timestamp. You then can format it using Twig's [`date()`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html) filter or with `format_date()` in a predefined Drupal date format.

In any variation of `field.html.twig` (`field--field-myfield.html.twig` etc.) do:

```
<div class="foo">
  {{ element['#object'].getCreatedTime | date('F j, Y') }}
</div>

<div class="bar">
  {{ element['#object'].getCreatedTime | format_date('html_datetime') }}
</div>
```

---

Source: Sample taken from [Accessing the original entity in field templates is hard](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2761525).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are wanting "node.createdtime"

```
<p class="post-date">{{ node.createdtime | date('F j, Y') }} at {{ node.createdtime | date('h:i a') }}</p>
```

This is for "node" template files. No loops or custom fields necessary as this comes from Drupal core.

```
{{ dump(node | keys) }}
```

Comment: Ok. I guess if the "node submitted" info is coming from a field it will probably depend on the field type... I would look to see if you have display settings control. Razeem Ahmed's answer is correct. date() in twig can't format "Sun, 01/11/2010". So whether in display settings, or in preprocessing, you'll need to ensure it renders as a timestamp.

Comment: You were right I was able to control the custom date  I created from drupal UI and implemented on custom DS view mode, however, I was not able to manipulate node created date implementing preprocessor.

$date = $variables['node']->getCreatedTime();
  $variables['date'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date, 'my_custom_date_formate_machine_name');

this is the code i am trying to implement on my preprocessor for that field but something is not right, where did i went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In twig, date filter only works for timestamps. In above case it is assuming as the present date and printing the date in long format.

You can get the created timestamp by writing a preprocess.

```
$timestamp = $variables['node']->created->value
```

Comment: how can i achieve my desired output then?

Comment: I cannot recreate the issue here. You need to access the arguments @date. The best way is to preprocess the data in you hook_preprocess() and then print the variable

Comment: @dejavu if you are writing a pre-process then you can access the created timestamp by $variables['node']->created->value

Comment: You can combine the `date` and `format_date` filters to get the timestamp and then format it with a predefined Drupal date format: `{{ node.field_my_date.value|date('U')|format_date('html_datetime') }}`

Answer (score 0):

> If you are in views and want to print **node created datetime** value in twig you need to:

**1. If your views HAS outputted Field (Authored On): then `{{ fields.created.content }}`**

**2. If NOT: then `{{ row._entity.created.value }}`**